# How to debug Push-AppveyorArtifact when it fails

Tags: appveyor

As part of my CI running on AppVeyor I'm uploading a log from the installer using `Push-AppveyorArtifact`. While most of the time it works perfectly for a single PR the upload fails with the following output:

```
Push-AppveyorArtifactInternal : Error uploading artifact to the storage: One or more         errors occurred.
At C:\Program Files\AppVeyor\BuildAgent\Modules\build-worker-api\build-worker-    api.psm1:209 char:2
    +     Push-AppveyorArtifactInternal -FullPath $fullPath -FileName $File ...
    +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Push-AppveyorArtifactInternal],     Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :     System.Exception,Appveyor.BuildAgent.Api.Utils.PushAppveyorArtifactInternalCmdlet
    Command executed with exception: Error uploading artifact to the storage: One or more errors occurred.
```

Given this output is not very informative  I am at a loss and have no idea how this can be debugged further. List of things I've tried:

- Contacted AppVeyort support - no reply for over a month
- Made sure that the file I am trying to upload exists and is not empty
- Since as part of the problematic pull request the process which creates this file fails to exit properly I've tried killing it manually, confirmed that it is no longer active and retied the upload - same error.
- Tried increasing the verbosity of `Push-AppveyorArtifact` by providing `-Verbose -Debug` which appears to be the highest verbosity level possible but no more info shows up.

It looks like the following sequence causes the upload to fail:

- The process which creates a log file which fails to upload later on is started and then we're waiting for it to finish with `wait-process` for 3 minutes
- If it finishes in the specified time the log file created it creates is uploaded successfully
- Since we want to know if the process exited or not we need to specify `-ErrorAction Stop` for the `wait-process` invocation.
- If `wait-process` raises an exception i.e. process is still running the `Push-AppveyorArtifact` fails with the error shown above

Comment: Sorry about that! What is your AppVeyor account name?

Comment: I don't have an AppVeyor account - this error shows up for a PR I've submitted to the project to which I regularly contribute. The discussion on AppVeyor forum is [here](https://help.appveyor.com/discussions/problems/30945-push-appveyorartifact-fails-with-a-cryptic-error).

Comment: I see that log is month-old and artifact uploads are working in [the most recent builds](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/NVAccess/nvda/builds/42046141/artifacts). Could you please confirm you are still getting errors on that project?

Comment: Yes, I still receive errors for that particular pull request. the most recent log is [here](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/NVAccess/nvda/builds/42078279). I've updated the question with the additional findings.

Comment: It's possible that the file you are trying to upload is locked. Try copying it before upload and then upload a copy.

Comment: Uploading a copy of this file indeed worked. I'm rather surprised this made a difference since, as described in the question, I've previously tried to kill the process and upload afterwards which didn't helped. At any rate it would be great if the error message here would be more informative. Also why the fact that the file is locked prevents it from being uploaded - as far as I understand uploading does not require exclusive access to the file?